# Array doesn't get serialized JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, xml, serialization

I have an Object 'Drawing'. In this object I have a list of 'DrawingItem'.

Which contains in my case 1 Oval and 1 Spline. The Oval and Spline extend DrawingItem. (DrawingItem is abstract).

And the Spline has a 'Point[] points' array so I can save all the points it goes through.

When I run:

```
XMLEncoder encoder=null;
try
{
    encoder=new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SERIALIZED_FILE_NAME)));
}
 catch(Exception e)
{
     System.out.println(e);
}
encoder.writeObject(drawing);
encoder.close();
```

I get the following

```
DRAWING
   ITEMLIST
      OVAL
         ANCHOR
         HEIGHT
         WIDTH
      OVAL
      SPLINE
         ANCHOR
         DEGREE
      SPLINE
   ITEMLIST
DRAWING
```

It shows me everything that both classes have, except for the Point[] array in Spline. I have a getter and setter for it as well.

I hope I'm missing something relatively easy, or could it be something more difficult?

Comment: Did you set `Point[]` to some value?  XMLEncoder typically won't write values to the stream that are still default values.  It skips them to save space.

Comment: @markspace When the class get's created I Immediately fill the array in the constructor. In my case I add 4 points to it when I create the 'Spline'. So it's impossible to be empty, even when it gets created the array has at least 4 points in it. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: If you fill the array with the same values every time in the ctor, XMLEncoder will consider that the default value.  That's what I mean.  If you then after the ctor set some different value, XMLEncoder will see a value besides the default, and save those values to its output.

Comment: @markspace And it won't serialize those 'default' values? When my program starts up I make a new Spline object and fill the array with points.  Even if it considers those 'default', I need the encoder to write those down. Would you have any idea as to how I would fix this?

Comment: @markspace And I give the Spline a 'degree' as well. At the same time as I fill the array. But it shows me the degree just fine.

Comment: I can't really tell why until I see your code.

Comment: We need to see your code.